# ros melodic and usb cam

Tags: ros, usb, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to install usb cam if I am working with ROS melodic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320124/ros-melodic-and-usb-cam/) by [Rabe1983](https://answers.ros.org/users/40694/rabe1983/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-04-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rabe1983](https://answers.ros.org/users/40694/rabe1983/) on 2019-04-02**:
Thank you for your help Reamees ! I appreciate that :)

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2019-04-02**:
@Rabe1983 if your problem is solved, please let us know and we can bet @Reamees answer turned into a comment and get this question marked as answered.

**Comment by [Rabe1983](https://answers.ros.org/users/40694/rabe1983/) on 2019-04-07**:
SOLVED! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`sudo apt install ros-melodic-usb-cam` does not work?
you can install it from source as well [usb_cam](https://github.com/ros-drivers/usb_cam)

---

Originally posted by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) with karma: 591 on 2019-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1